# Подлежащее + "как" + повелительная форма глагола

Tags: пунктуация

Как записывается, например, такое выражение?

*Подушка как зашевелись!*

(показана внезапность)

Тут нужно тире перед "как" или нет?

Comment: На мой взгляд, так не говорят.

Comment: Подушка возьми да зашевелись!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подушка как зашевелись! - фраза разговорная, даже просторечная, чаще употребляется в том виде, как сказал  Alex_ander:  Подушка возьми да зашевелись! Никаких знаков препинания нет, потому что **как** - частица.

По А. А. Шахматову, употребление единственного числа повелительного наклонения (чаще всего в сочетании с императивом «возьми») для выражения внезапного, неожиданного действия в конструкциях типа «Ему бы промолчать, а он возьми и скажи» - это остаток древнерусского прошедшего времени аориста (мгновенное действие в прошлом). https://studopedia.org/8-75496.html